# "npm run" fails with ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I have an existing project which I lately installed on a new equipment.
It is a Laravel + vue project.

When I run `npm run watch` I get the following error:

```
> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…

10% building 1/3 modules 2 active ...er/index.js??ref--5-4!/var/www/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!/var/www/resources/sass/app.scssError: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:186:6
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:178:3
    at loadLoader (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:188:6
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:12)
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:178:3
    at loadLoader (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:295:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:446:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:739:10)
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:981:14
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13
    at AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:138:29
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:346:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/var/www/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /var/www/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:55:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I am using Node.js v17.3.0, npm version 8.3.0, and webpack 4.41.4.

Comment: @guyaloni Update web pack version to 6 and then run `npx mix`. See if it works.

Comment: @guyaloni  . the sass problem you can fix like: You can fix this problem with:

`npm uninstall node-sass

Install sass instead of node-sass

npm i -D sass`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Node.js version 17 has switched to using OpenSSL 3.0. They [advise](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0/#openssl-3-0):

> While OpenSSL 3.0 APIs should be mostly compatible with those provided by OpenSSL 1.1.1, we do anticipate some ecosystem impact due to tightened restrictions on the allowed algorithms and key sizes.
>
> If you hit an `ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED` error in your application with Node.js 17, it’s likely that your application or a module you’re using is attempting to use an algorithm or key size which is no longer allowed by default with OpenSSL 3.0. A command-line option, `--openssl-legacy-provider`, has been added to revert to the legacy provider as a temporary workaround for these tightened restrictions.

This has been [resolved](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/14584) in Webpack versions 5 and 6, but [there are no plans](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947513562) to backport this fix to version 4.

To pass the `--openssl-legacy-provider` flag to Node, you can prefix your command with the environment variable assignment:

```sh
NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider npm run watch
```

Comment: Here is a full guide on how to fix on different platforms: https://gankrin.org/how-to-fix-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-in-node-js-or-react/

Comment: In Windows command prompt: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && npm run watch`

Answer (score 18):

What worked for me (on Ubuntu 22.04) was adding this to the package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
  }
}
```

I found the complete answer in this article by Borislav Hadzhiev: [Fix - error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-error-digital-envelope-routines-unsupported)

Answer (score 11):

##### Linux or macOS terminal:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

##### Windows cmd:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

then run your application, it should work

Answer (score 7):

Follow below if using Windows Powershell:

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS = '--openssl-legacy-provider'
yarn run dev
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using angular then
run

```bash
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider ng serve
ng serve
```

to run project

Answer (score 2):

Add .npmrc file parallel to the src folder and add below in it.

```
node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

[.npmrc File changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwxhm.png)

[.npmrc File location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8bla.png)