# ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook') VueJS, Nuxt, Npx

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, npx

I have downloaded and setup the an existing old code on my laptop and did `npm install` to install the necessary packages and did `npm audit fix --force` to solve the vulnerabilities. When i do `npm run start` it gives error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Work\Xampp\htdocs\folder-name\node_modules\nuxt\bin\nuxt.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

when i run `npm run dev` it tells to run `npx nuxi dev` or other commands using `npx nuxi ---`

now when i run `npx nuxi dev` it gives the below error

```
ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook')                                                                           18:25:30

  at nuxtBootstrapVue (node_modules\bootstrap-vue\nuxt\index.js:34:13)
  at installModule (/C:/Work/Xampp/htdocs/folder-name/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:416:9)
  at async initNuxt (/C:/Work/Xampp/htdocs/folder-name/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:1825:7)
  at async load (/C:/Work/Xampp/htdocs/folder-name/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6779:9)
  at async Object.invoke (/C:/Work/Xampp/htdocs/folder-name/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6840:5)
  at async _main (/C:/Work/Xampp/htdocs/folder-name/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:50:20)
```

facing `ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook')` when trying to run command `npx nuxi dev`, i have tried to delete and reinstall node modules as well

Comment: Check your node version.

Comment: i have downgraded my npm and node versions as well, but still its same

Comment: Try 18 or 16 rather.

Comment: my current node version is v16.17.0, also tried 14.17.0, will try with 18 now

Comment: Nuxt3 clearly states that you need to use the latest LTS node version aka v18.

Comment: @kissu currently I have got the latest version v18.13.0 but still the same error, I am using Kernel: Linux 6.0.0-kali3-amd64

Comment: @GabrielRogath be sure that you don't have some older `node_modules` already populated. Double check in the given directory that you're using the given version. You could maybe also nuke your lockfile and create a new one to see if that one fixes it. And, open a brand new question with more context/details or even a public repo.

Comment: @kissu ,After a long research I found out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582385/10412027  was the issue and it fixed the problem

Comment: @Saad did you find any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @Rajan which version of node are you using

Comment: @Saad v18.13.0 LTS

Comment: is this the same version that the project was built on?

Comment: I had to upgrade core-js version to match with the version of my installed node, if not then you need to use node version that the project was built on.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still facing this error, changing your nuxt.config.js from

```
export default {
  // your code
}
```

to

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/bridge'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // your code
})
```

solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correction in the code from Srijay:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/bridge'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // Your code
})
```

The parenthesis is required.

Reference: https://nuxt.com/docs/bridge/overview