# Cannot start nuxt: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook') Nuxt.js Vue.js migrating from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to migrate from nuxt 2 to nuxt 3 and looking for the solution of error

`Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook')`

---

```ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/bridge'

export default defineNuxtConfig{
  // your code
}
```

^^^ I have try this one but it's not working.

ref: [ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hook') VueJS, Nuxt, Npx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74993699/error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-hook-vuejs-nuxt-npx)