# when i clone others github repo react project, try to run in localhost, i am getting error

Tags: reactjs, github, openssl

PS C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio> npm start

```
> react-frontend-dev-portfolio@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.8/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /react-frontend-dev-portfolio
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /react-frontend-dev-portfolio/
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\ksche\OneDrive\Documents\projects\new_project\react-frontend-dev-portfolio\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v18.18.0
ChatGPT

Comment: Have you installed the node packages (packages): npm i or npm install

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["npm run" fails with ERR\_OSSL\_EVP\_UNSUPPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582072/npm-run-fails-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported)

Comment: yes I have installed node packages