# Error found node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

Tags: node.js, json

something has changed in my program structure and due to its complexity i cannot exactly point where the problem. Ever since my application crushed and no longer working i have tried different approaches like deleting the node module packages and reinstalling them but still wont work. whenever i try to run npm start i get the following errors:

[I got this kind of Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abroe.png)

and below is my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version"
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["npm run" fails with ERR\_OSSL\_EVP\_UNSUPPORTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582072/npm-run-fails-with-err-ossl-evp-unsupported)

Comment: Please do not post your errors as images. If you would have copied the error message from there, you would've found the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported